# How to Invite friends for non-canvas app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

to make app viral,we want to invite friends using request (but it only works for Canvas app

We are having non-canvas app. What is the best available method to make it viral ?

[from the lots of facebook doc, i understand request only works for canvas app!, and not for website, correct me if understanding is wrong]

Currently we are taking publish_stream permission and sending to user's friends (after properly taking user's consent), but hitting by 341 error.

Is there any way out, so user's friends can be invited for non-canvas apps ?

PS: we dont want to send apprequest (which requires app Access token). We want to invite friends of user on behalf of user.

Anyone from FB here ?

Raxit Sheth